# Is the sentence "For every integer 3<k<15 " written correctly?

Tags: mathematics

In my mathematics paper, I wrote：

```
For 3<k<15, ... .
```

I later discovered that k needs to be emphasised as an integer.
So I wrote this:

```
For every integer 3<k<15, ... .
```

I'm not sure if above sentence  is normal. I frequently encounter the following sentence.

```
For every integer k>3, ... .
```

Note that k is close to the word “integer”.

So I would like to ask if the above write up is correct. I've also tried writing like this, but I'm also not sure if it's the norm.

```
 For every integer k with 3<k<15, ... .
```

Comment: Is *n* an integer, a real, or what? Should we consider every possible *n* that is greater than sin(k), or do you just assert that there exists some *n* that is greater than sin(k), or what?

Comment: This quetion would probably get better answers on one of the math stackexchange sites, where they could also share how to express this in mathematical notation.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks. We don't care whether n is real (integer) or not.

Comment: @ThePhoton I always thought the math stackexchange  was for math problems, not language. So I didn't ask it on the math stack.

Comment: @ThePhoton The second half of the sentence is not my concern. My question is whether k must be immediately followed by the word "integer".

Comment: That's not English, it's Mathlish.

Comment: yes, this is more about how a fellow mathematician would understand your writing, rather than how an average English speaker would.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that this is also a matter of mathematics (maybe it belongs to mathematical writing).  (I modified the way I asked questions. My concern here is with language rather than mathematical correctness.)

Comment: Another alternative would be "for _k_ = 4, ..., 14", every mathematician would understand from this that _k_ is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one is reading it would help to specify **k** as the element of interest. Finding it hidden in 3<k<15 will make the average reader chortle with "Of course 3 is less than 15".

With that in mind I would use, "For every integer k where 3<k<15 we have the following claim;"

A good mathematician will not get lost but we generally write for the average reader.